# how to get only specific variable value from json response(facebook response)

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I want only a specific value(say "name") from my generated output. I used this code 
 `var_dump($request_object_details);` to generate the below output.

What output I am getting:-

```
array(6) { ["id"]=> string(26) "514484461930096_1446926141"   ["application"]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(18) "Pocket Financetest" ["id"]=> string(15) "270339389736782" } ["to"]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(12) "Prince Singh" ["id"]=> string(10) "1446926141" } ["from"]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(14) "Ashutosh Singh" ["id"]=> string(15) "100003645579131" } ["message"]=> string(16) "My Great Request" ["created_time"]=> string(24) "2013-01-17T03:45:36+0000" }
```

I used the below code to get the above output:

```
         <?php
        require_once('phps/fbsdk/src/facebook.php');
        $config = array
        (
          'appId' => '270339389736782',
          'secret' => '667e1795cc1f308f312d49d6b1c17cb8',
        );
        $facebook = new Facebook($config);
        //get the request ids from the query parameter
         $request_ids = explode(',', $_REQUEST['request_ids']);

         //build the full_request_id from request_id and user_id
          function build_full_request_id($request_id, $user_id) {
          return $request_id . '_' . $user_id;
         }  

         //for each request_id, build the full_request_id and delete request
     foreach ($request_ids as $request_id)
      {
         $uid = $facebook->getUser();

         $full_request_id = build_full_request_id($request_id, $uid); 
        $request_object_details = $facebook->api("/$full_request_id");
        var_dump($request_object_details);//This is giving me the output

        try {
         $delete_success = $facebook->api("/$full_request_id",'DELETE');
         if ($delete_success) {
            echo "Successfully deleted " . $full_request_id;}
         else {
           echo "Delete failed".$full_request_id;}
        }
        catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        echo "error=".$e;}
        }
     ?>
```

Comment: are you getting json response in `$request_object_details` this variable?

Comment: Do you want `$request_object_details['from']['id']` ?

Comment: @DeminothBono Yes exactly i want the same as you said

Comment: @Ashutosh haha give a point to my comment XD

Comment: @Ashutosh oh.. maybe I didn't got your point..

Comment: @DeminothBono I mean help me to get the $request_object_details['from']['id']

Comment: @Ashutosh just use $request_object_details['from']['id'] like normal variable. facebook sdk parse response already so you can use it like normal array.

Comment: @DeminothBono i wrote `var_dump($request_object_details);` instead of var_dump($request_object_details); but is shows error like `Server error The website encountered an error while retrieving http://localhost/ashutosh/pocketFinance/test.php?request_ids=613508101998458. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.`

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear but still I am posting some sort of code for you.

Use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Do like this : It will return object

```
$obj = json_decode($request_object_details);
$result= $obj->id;
```

OR

You can use `json_decode` and convert it into the array:

```
$request_object_details = $facebook->api("/$full_request_id");
$result=json_decode($request_object_details, true);
```

The second parameter will make decoded json string into an associative arrays.

Now you can directly use :

```
echo $result['id'];
echo $result['application'];
```

and so on...

Hope it'll help you.

Comment: i tried your both suggestions but it is not printing any values. I don't know why.